# Find a basis for Kernel and Image of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:

$$A =  \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\            
        0 & 2 \\ 
        0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Find a basis for $ImT_A$ and $kerT_A$

So far, I've found a basis for $ker T_A$ (which is {1,0}). I know that I should probably use the Rank-nullity theorem in order to find $Im T_A$, but I don't know how.

The answer is $ImT_A$ = {1,2,1}, but how do I find it?

Comment: Hint: another term for the range of a matrix is the column space of the matrix.

Comment: Just read that: The column space of a matrix is the image or range of the corresponding matrix transformation. Does that mean that given a matrix ${(a,b,c;d,e,f)}^T$ the vectors [a b c] and [d e f] will be the image (if they are linearly independent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me write $e_1 = (1,0)^\top, e_2 = (0,1)^\top.$  then you have $$Ae_1 = 0, Ae_2 = (1,2,1)^\top.$$ this means $e_1$ is in the $\ker(A)$ and $(1, 2,1 )^\top$ is in the $image(A).$  we also have sum of the dimensions of $\ker(A) $ and $image(A)$ is $2.$ therefore $$\ker(A) = span\{e_1\}, image(A) = span\{(1, 2, 1)^\top\}. $$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $T_A(\mathbf x) = A\mathbf x$ for a $2\times 1$ column vector $\mathbf x$.  Then let's try to figure out what the image of this function is.

---

First let's just consider a general real-valued matrix (general results are usually nicer than specific ones, IMO).  Let's consider the transformation $f(\mathbf x) = B\mathbf x$ for an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ and an $m\times 1$ matrix $\mathbf x$.  Then what does the image of this function even mean?  It is the space of all $n\times 1$ vectors that can be reached by multiplying $m\times 1$ vectors by $B$.  Thus $\operatorname{Im}(f) = \{\mathbf y \in M_{n\times 1}(\Bbb R) \mid \mathbf y = B\mathbf x\}$.  Obviously we can't assume that *every* $n\times 1$ vectors is in this set.

So let's take a closer look at this multiplication $B\mathbf x$.  Let $B = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nm}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf b_1 & \cdots & \mathbf b_m \end{bmatrix}$, where $\mathbf b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $B$.  Then

$$B\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1m} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nm}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_m\end{bmatrix} = x_1\mathbf b_1 + \cdots + x_m\mathbf b_m$$

From this, we can see that the image of the function $f$ is just the set of all linear combinations of the columns of $B$ -- i.e. the column space of $B$:
$$\operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{col}(B)$$

---

So the image of $T_A$ is just the column space of $A$.  In this case, a basis for the column space is very apparent, so:

$$\operatorname{Im}(T_A) = \operatorname{col}(A) = \operatorname{span}\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right) = \operatorname{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$